# Replace all instances of character in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string

```
 var str=  'asdf<br>dfsdfs<br>dsfsdf<br>fsfs<br>dfsdf<br>fsdf';
```

I want to replace `<br>` with `\r` by using

```
 str.replace(/<br>/g,'\r');
```

, but it is replacing only the first `<br>`... Any idea why?

Comment: `replace(/<br>/g,'\r')` replaces all `<br>` here ... Or did you only want to replace the first `<br>`?

Comment: Something else must be going on. The code snippet you pasted does what you want. Here's the output from node.js:`
'asdf<br>dfsdfs<br>dsfsdf<br>fsfs<br>dfsdf<br>fsdf'.replace(/<br>/g,'\r') = 'asdf\rdfsdfs\rdsfsdf\rfsfs\rdfsdf\rfsdf'`

Comment: This should work, have you made sure this is the original code?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The code should work - with the `/g` flag, it should replace all `<br>`s. It's possible the problem is elsewhere.

Try this:

```
str = str.replace(/<br>/g, '\n');
```

`'\n'` is probably more appropriate than `\r` - it should be globally recognized as a newline, while `\r` isn't common on its own. On Firefox, for example, `\r` isn't rendered as a newline.

Answer (score -9):

Use :

```
str.replace(/<br>/gi,'\r');
```

/g is only for the first match. /gi is for global replacement